# How to install QGIS on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation

I am attempting to install QGIS on my Ubuntu 22.04. I am following these steps https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu. Unfortunately I don't understand the following instructions:

Add the QGIS repo for the latest stable QGIS (3.30.x ‘s-Hertogenbosch) to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qgis.sources:

```
Types: deb deb-src
URIs: https://qgis.org/debian
Suites: your-distributions-codename
Architectures: amd64
Components: main
Signed-By: /etc/apt/keyrings/qgis-archive-keyring.gpg
```

I tried adding a text file named qgis.sources to that directory with the text included. I received an error stating I did not have permission to do so. How do I change that, or how do I create the text file through the terminal where I can use sudo. Obviously I am very new to Linux, so I might not be on the right track at all here.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What text editor are you using? If terminal-based - nano, vi/vim, for example - then use `sudo your-editor /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qgis.sources`.

Comment: ... see for example [How do I get permissions to edit system configuration files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92379/how-do-i-get-permissions-to-edit-system-configuration-files)